# Singularity of a function $ f(z) $

Tags: complex-analysis

Which type of singularity the function
               $ f(z)= \frac{e^z}{z(1- e^{-z})} $ at $ z=0 $

I Know, we find the singularity of a function by expanding the given function by using Laurent series expansion.

I tried like this.  $ f(z)= \frac{e^z}{z(1- e^{-z})} $
                    $ f(z)= \frac{1}{z}{e^z}{(1- e^{-z})^{-1}} $
$ f(z)= \frac{1}{z}({e^z+1+e^{-z}+e^{-2z}+\dots)} $
from this i concluded that
 this function has essential singularity at $z=0$.
Is my conclusion correct??

Please help me. thank you.

Comment: $z=0$ is a zero both for $z$ and for $1-e^{-z}$, while the numerator is never zero. Hence it is a pole of order $2$.

Comment: $e^{-z}$ has infinite terms, how pole of order 2? can you explain.... @FedericaMaggioni

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hints:**
 1. Function $f(z)$ can be rewritten as
$$f(z)= \dfrac{e^z}{z(1- e^{-z})}=\dfrac{e^{2z}}{z({e^{z}-1})}=\dfrac{ze^{2z}}{z^2({e^{z}-1})}=\dfrac{e^{2z}}{z^2}h(z)$$
 2. Function $h(z)=\dfrac{z}{e^{z}-1}$ has a removable singularity at $z=0.$

Comment: later function has a pole of order 2. so, what is the conclusion?  @M.Strochyk

Comment: Thus $f(z)$ has a pole of order $2$ at $z=0.$